# protractor - wait for previous it block to finish before next

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

how to synchronize the it blocks,

```
var kc = 1;
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
      for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
      it('should add a todo', function() {
        kc = 10;
        hello = 10;
      });
    }
  });
describe('Print kc',function(){
  var k = kc1();
  expect(kc).toEqual(10);
});
```

Output: Value of kc is : 1

expected : Value of kc is : 10

Comment: First of all, where would you need this for, I mean, why would you do the log? Second. The `describe`s and `it`'s are async. That means that they first need to be resolved before `kc`, is updated. You can validate this by adding a `browser.sleep(5000)` in your `it` block, you will see that the `console.log()` will be printed before the it is done.

Comment: Thanks @wswebcreation it's not actually for logging, it's for use in a different it block in the next sequence, the value is not 10 when i use it below, it is still 1. i'm searching for a method which will do the task asap when the it block is finished, instead of waiting for a predefined time.

Comment: Can you then clearify your question. I still don't understand what you want. Do you want to "pass" the value? Maybe you can set the variable in a `beforeAll`m, or add a property to the `browser`-object of protractor.

Comment: I've updated the code in the question, I think it makes it more readable. @wswebcreation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then you want to store a value in a variable and access it in different `describe`s.

You can use `browser.params` to store a "global" variable. Then you need to add the `params` attribute to your `protractor-config`:

```
...
params: {
    kc: 1
}
...
```

Now you can access your variable with `browser.params.kc`, so your code would look like this:

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
      for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
      it('should add a todo', function() {
        browser.params.kc = 10;
        hello = 10;
      });
    }
  });
describe('Print kc',function(){
  var k = kc1();
  expect(browser.params.kc).toEqual(10);
});
```

The advantage of using `browser.params` to store your value is that you can pass another value directly to the protractor instance like:

`protractor protractor-config.js --params.kc 5`<- kc now has the value 5

Does this help? Or did i misunderstood you?